# Cannot update eclipse ADT to 23.0.3 even after trying everything found on google

Tags: java, android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, adt

I am using eclipse for the first time. I copied an adt-bundle and everything worked fine until i connected to the internet. Then every time I open eclipse it says

This Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version 23.0.0 or above.  Current version is 22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508.  Please update ADT to the latest version.

I tried to update by going to help>install new software

and used both options

1.archive(by downloading plug in) and

2.work with 'https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/'

but end up getting the same error

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Android Development Tools 23.0.3.1327240 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.feature.group 23.0.3.1327240)
  Software currently installed: Android Developer Tools 22.0.5.v201307292155--757759 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product 22.0.5.v201307292155--757759)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    ADT XML Overlay 23.0.3.1327240 (overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay 23.0.3.1327240)
    ADT XML Overlay 22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508 (overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay 22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Android Development Tools 23.0.3.1327240 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.feature.group 23.0.3.1327240)
    To: overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay [23.0.3.1327240]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Android Development Tools 22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508)
    To: overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay [22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: ADT Package 22.0.5.v201307292155--757759 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.feature.group 22.0.5.v201307292155--757759)
    To: com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 22.0.5
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Android Developer Tools 22.0.5.v201307292155--757759 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product 22.0.5.v201307292155--757759)
    To: com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.feature.group [22.0.5.v201307292155--757759]
```

I tried everything, like uninstalling current adt and then installing, installing one at a time, copying files from tools/proguard etc. Nothing worked. Can somebody please help me?

Comment: Lately, I've had more luck installing normal Eclipse and then installing the ADT plug-in than with the ADT bundle...

Comment: Also, since you are new to ADT, maybe have a look at Android Studio - Android development is more and more moving there...

Comment: Switch to Android Studio ;)

Comment: Correct, switch o here: https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html This will be the official featured IDE for Android Apps

Comment: I had same problem.What i have done deleted the whole adt and downloaded the latest adt solved my problem.There is an problem on upgrade to latest version , you have download the new adt for the latest version

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me couple of times....This happens when you update eclipse ADT. There is nothing you can do to fix it other than download a fresh copy of eclipse ADT .Switch to Android studio . It get updates more frequently and it's easy to code using it. Android studio is still behind eclipse ADT but Google is updating it faster to change that.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the adt folder and install eclipse as given below

Steps for updating eclipse

```
 1. Download eclipse from the official site
 2. Download and install jdk latest version
 3. After installing the eclipse , Go to  Help > Install New Software.
 4. Click Add, in the top-right corner.
 5. In the Add Repository dialog that appears, enter "ADT Plugin" for the     
        Name and the following URL for the Location:
        https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
 6. Click OK.
 7. In the Available Software dialog, select the checkbox next to Developer Tools and click Next.
 8. In the next window, you'll see a list of the tools to be downloaded. Click Next.
 9.Read and accept the license agreements, then click Finish.
 10. If you get a security warning saying that the authenticity or validity of the software can't be established, click OK.
 11. When the installation completes, restart Eclipse.
```